# How to execute more than one testng test suite xml from one gradle task

Tags: testing, gradle

I wrote a gradle task. From that task i am running my testng test suite like this.

task upsSmoke(type: JavaExec) {

```
classpath += files('conf')

main = 'org.testng.TestNG'
enter code here

args '-testjar', 'build/libs/*.jar' ,'-xmlpathinjar','testsuites/abc.xml', '-d' , reportFolder
classpath +=configurations.runtime
systemProperties 'logDir': logFolder
systemProperties 'testReportOutputFolder': reportFolder
systemProperties 'executionSummaryReportName': executionSummaryReportName
systemProperties 'com.tc.productkey.path': licenseFile
ignoreExitValue = 'true'
```

}

abc.xml is my test suite. I want to run one more suite in the same task which is xyz.xml which is also present in the same testsuite folder.

I tried

```
args '-testjar', 'build/libs/*.jar' ,'-xmlpathinjar','testsuites/abc.xml' 'testsuites/xyz.xml', '-d' , reportFolder
```

but it did not work. Can you guys help in doing that.

Comment: Why aren't you using Gradle's `Test` task?

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser: just for design sake, i can have many tasks like this in my gradle file.

Comment: You can also have many `Test` tasks. `Test` is a much more powerful (and more idiomatic) way to run tests. From what I see in the docs, it also makes it easy to run multiple TestNG suites.

Comment: Ok i ll try to explore this task :)